# Drawing rects using Raphael,storing coords in database, retrieve the coords re-draw the shapes

Tags: javascript, php, json, canvas, raphael

sorry for the long title, but it pretty much puts my problem in a nutshell. 
I am currently drawing a rectangle using the following :

```
for (var i = 0; i <= fixedrow; i++) {           
    for (var j = 0; j <= fixedcolumn; j++) {    

        var offseti = i;                        //An offset was needed to ensure each newly drawn rectangle places at the right spacing
        var moveDown = (i + 25 - offseti) * i;  //between eachother. 

        var offsetj = j;
        var moveRight = (j + 20 - offsetj) * j;

        rectangle = paper.rect(moveRight, moveDown, 15, 20).attr({      
            fill : "green"                                                                              
        });
```

This basically draws my shape and depending on how many rows, columns the user enters, it draws that amount of rectangles and spaces them out evenly (see image).

[image]

I then save each shape being drawn using my function save(X,Y,ID). I get the X coord of each shape by feeding in the moveRight variable from above and moveDown for the Y coord. This passes through to the save function that looks like this:

```
function save(xin, yin, idin) {
var id = idin;
var x = xin;
var y = yin;

$.ajax('save.php', {
    type : 'post',
    dataType : 'text',
    data : 'x=' + x + '&y=' + y + '&id=' + id,
    success : function(){}
})
};
```

The X, Y and id get stored in the database no problem.

However, when it comes to loading the saved data, and re-drawing the rectangles, I am getting a strange issue where it cuts of one of the results, and leaves a blank space where a shape should be (see image).

[image]

Notice the blank spot at the top left. I've checked each ID and it seems that the last rectangle is being left out, but somehow the whole structure is being shifted across one to make it display this way.

My code for retrieving the stored data and drawing the rects is as follows:

load() is called by pressing the button in the screenshot and calls this:

```
function load() {   
        $.ajax('load.php', {
        type : 'GET',
        success : drawLoad 
    })  
};
```

the load script is as follows:

```
<?php
header ("Content-type: application/json");

$conn = new           PDO("mysql:host=****.****.co.uk;dbname=****;","****","****");

$results = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM seats_table ORDER BY y,x");
$row = $results->fetch();
$data= array();
while ($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $data[] = $row;
}    
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

And the way I use the returned Json is:

```
function drawLoad(data) {
//if (paper == null) // Checks that the canvas/paper hasn't already been created (Decides whether to add to current paper or make new one).
    paper = Raphael("content", 1920, 900); // Creates the paper if one hasn't already been done so.

var start = function () {
    this.odx = 0;
    this.ody = 0;
    this.animate({
        "fill-opacity" : 0.2
    }, 500);
},
move = function (dx, dy) {
    this.translate(dx - this.odx, dy - this.ody);
    this.odx = dx;
    this.ody = dy;
},
up = function () {
    this.animate({
        "fill-opacity" : 1
    }, 500);
    update(this.odx, this.ody, this.id);
    alert(this.id);
};

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var ID = data[i].ID;
    var x = data[i].x;
    var y = data[i].y;
    var isBooked = data[i].isBooked;
    var price = data[i].price;
    var seat_ID = data[i].seat_ID;

    rectangle = paper.rect(x, y, 15, 20).attr({fill : "green"}); 
    rectangle.drag(move, start, up);
    //alert("ID = " + ID + " X = " + x + " Y = " + y);
    var clickHandler = function () {                //This clickHandler will detect when a user double clicks on a seat icon.

            };

}
};
```

Can anyone point out what might be the cause of this issue? Please bear in mind I've removed any validation and what not to reduce the code content in the post and hopefully make it slightly more readable.

Thanks in advance for any replies, David.

**UPDATE:** Thanks too everyone below who helped me with this issue, but I've managed to solve the problem regarding the missing rectangle. I was using ORDER BY x,y in my sql statement instead of BY seat_ID. This small change now displays all the stored rectangles.

New problem however. When I try to load the shapes from the database, they are not where they should be on the canvas/paper. Is there something I am overlooking regarding the coordinates taken from my canvas/paper sized at 1920x900 that is causing the coordinates I store to not match up to those on my paper/canvas?

Again, any help is appreciated in this.

The below screenshot shows me just adding 25 rectangles and moving the bottom right one to a new position. You can see the url is passing through the id, x and a y coord. 
[image]

Here is the database table after moving rectangle seat_ID 25:

[image: after moving a shape.]

I think the way I am getting these new coords is the problem. Below is my current way of getting the coords of a moved shape:

```
var start = function () {
    this.odx = 0;
    this.ody = 0;
    this.animate({
        "fill-opacity" : 0.2
    }, 500);        
},
move = function (dx, dy) {
    this.translate(dx - this.odx, dy - this.ody);
    this.odx = dx;
    this.ody = dy;
},
up = function () {
    this.animate({
        "fill-opacity" : 1
    }, 500);
    update(this.odx, this.ody, this.id);
    alert(this.id);
};
```

the update function is basically the same as the save one, and seems to be working as it is passing through all the variables and storing them in the database, which leads me now to think I have made an obvious error in trying to obtain the newly moved shapes coords.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:** Just realised the values I am getting from this.odx and this.ody are actually the difference between the starting coords and the ending, not the actual ending coords. I need to figure out the best way to work out the final coord from this information.

Comment: In `drawLoad`, before the `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {` line, could you `console.log(drawLoad.length` and check that it is indeed `25`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, having internet issues. I've just did as you asked, however the console doesn't seem to be logging anything at all using console.log(drawLoad.length);

Comment: Oh sorry, the variable is `data` not `drawLoad`.

Comment: Is this line right, $row = $results->fetch();  (you have this twice, once before the loop and once as part of the loop). Aren't you fetching a row, and then doing nothing with it before the loop ?

Comment: @JoeFrambach yes, you're right, I should have spotted that type myself. It now outputs the number 24, so just one short. The databse does contain 25 records however.

Comment: @ian you are right, forgot to remove that extra execute line before submitting the code, thanks.

Comment: Np, will set as an answer. Nice screenshots btw, it does help to quickly isolate the problem :).

Comment: I also just managed to realise what was causing it to not draw all the shapes again. In my SQL statement I order by x,y and it should be by seat_ID. After changing that, it now draws all the shapes correctly as long as their original coordinates haven't been altered. Shall I mark this question as answered and start a new one for the issue about not drawing to the correct coordinates, or can I just edit this one?

Comment: So there is either a problem with saving altered coordinates, or loading rectangles from coordinates that have been altered.  Alter some coordinates and check that they are saved correctly in the database.  Check that the load JSON for altered coordinates is correct.  Then, check your draw function again.

Comment: @James thanks for replying, I have just double checked that each coordinate is updated in the database after moving a shape and it is updating the x and y columns to the values being returned from the canvas. However I am thinking it has something to do with how I get those coordinates. At the moment I am reading in the new coordinates using my draggable() method that sends the new coordinates when I release a shape. I will update the original question with a couple screen shots and some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so for anyone interested, I have figured it out, and it was quite simple. all I had to do was create a variable for x and y and set them to    this.getBBox().x and    this.getBBox().y which gives me the x and y coords for the top left of each element. So I edited my drag function to the following :

```
var start = function () {
    this.odx = 0;
    this.ody = 0;
    this.animate({
        "fill-opacity" : 0.2
    }, 500);
},
move = function (dx, dy) {
    x = this.getBBox().x;
    y = this.getBBox().y;       
    this.translate(dx - this.odx, dy - this.ody);       
    this.odx = dx;
    this.ody = dy;
},
up = function () {
    this.animate({
        "fill-opacity" : 1
    }, 500);
    update(x,y,this.id); //use the bbox values for the update function.
    alert(this.id);
};
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like its because there is an initial fetch that isn't used before the main loop.

```
$row = $results->fetch();  // not needed
$data = array();
while ($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

The first line can be discarded, as you want them all gathered in the loop.